# I am am facing issue in left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

Query 1 :

```
SELECT b.id,
b.bid,
b.productname,
b.brandname, 
b.producttype, b.sku,
b.cat_id,
b.brandname,
b.costprice,
b.pweight,
b.monthly,
b.discountcodes, 
b.seller_id FROM `buyde_product` b 
where b.sku in ( SELECT buyde_new_new_sku.sku FROM buyde_new_new INNER JOIN buyde_new_new_sku ON buyde_new_new.cat_id = buyde_new_new_sku.cat_id)
```

Initially, I wrote above query as that time I need above details only 
Now I want to add one more detail from `buyde_brand` table so i thought to use Left Join and using below query but it gives me an error when trying in PHPMyAdmin.

Can anyone see my code that where I am wrong?

```
SELECT b.id,
    b.bid,
    b.productname,
    b.producttype, b.sku,
    b.cat_id,
    b.brandname,
    b.costprice,
    b.pweight,
    b.monthly,
    ba.brandname, 
    ba.bid,
    b.discountcodes, 
    b.seller_id FROM `buyde_product` b 
    where b.sku in ( SELECT buyde_new_new_sku.sku FROM buyde_new_new INNER 
JOIN buyde_new_new_sku ON buyde_new_new.cat_id = buyde_new_new_sku.cat_id)

LEFT JOIN `buyde_brand` ba 
ON b.bid = ba.bid
```

ERROR: in phpmyadmin

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN `buyde_brand` ba 
>       ON b.bid = ba.bid LIMIT 0, 25' at line 16`

Update : `SELECT b.id, b.bid, b.productname, b.producttype, b.sku, b.cat_id, b.brandname, b.costprice, b.pweight, b.monthly, ba.brandname, ba.bid, b.discountcodes, b.seller_id FROM`buyde_product`b LEFT JOIN`buyde_brand`ba ON b.bid = ba.bid`

if i run above query by removing

`where b.sku in ( SELECT buyde_new_new_sku.sku FROM buyde_new_new INNER 
    JOIN buyde_new_new_sku ON buyde_new_new.cat_id = buyde_new_new_sku.cat_id)`

this part then it runs but i need to first fetch as per this condition and then want to add bid from `buyde_brand`

Comment: Your joins should be before your filters. Move the join to before the `where b.sku`.

Comment: Set your left join after the `FROM buyde_product b `

Comment: @Rob and Sebastain Bosch , thank you i got the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your `LEFT JOIN` after the condition (`WHERE`) of your query. You have to set the `LEFT JOIN` on the table part of your query. See the following:

```
SELECT 
    b.id,
    b.bid,
    b.productname,
    b.producttype, b.sku,
    b.cat_id,
    b.brandname,
    b.costprice,
    b.pweight,
    b.monthly,
    ba.brandname, 
    ba.bid,
    b.discountcodes, 
    b.seller_id 
FROM `buyde_product` b LEFT JOIN `buyde_brand` ba ON b.bid = ba.bid
WHERE b.sku IN (
    SELECT buyde_new_new_sku.sku 
    FROM buyde_new_new INNER JOIN buyde_new_new_sku ON buyde_new_new.cat_id = buyde_new_new_sku.cat_id
)
```

This query should also fit your new requirements to first filter the `buyde_product` table and then `LEFT JOIN` on this filtered table. The result should be same with this solution. Another solution would be to put your original query into a sub-select and `LEFT JOIN` on this sub-select.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL syntax is wrong; the correct order is `SELECT` - `FROM` - `JOIN` - `WHERE` (- `GROUP BY` - `ORDER BY`).
In your query you put `LEFT JOIN` after `WHERE` clause, that is incorrect.
You should write it like this:

```
SELECT b.id,
    b.bid,
    b.productname,
    b.producttype, b.sku,
    b.cat_id,
    b.brandname,
    b.costprice,
    b.pweight,
    b.monthly,
    ba.brandname, 
    ba.bid,
    b.discountcodes, 
    b.seller_id
FROM `buyde_product` b 
LEFT JOIN `buyde_brand` ba 
ON b.bid = ba.bid
    where b.sku in ( SELECT buyde_new_new_sku.sku FROM buyde_new_new INNER 
JOIN buyde_new_new_sku ON buyde_new_new.cat_id = buyde_new_new_sku.cat_id)
```